# Filter all brands that have total sales >500 units in the entire year

Tags: sql, sql-server, subtotal

Data present for 2019 only

| Brand | Date | Unit Sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B1 | 20190101 | 10 |
| B1 | 20190102 | 5 |
| B1 | 20190103 | 100 |
| B2 | 20190101 | 50 |
| B2 | 20190103 | 500 |

Answer (score 1):

A simple group by clause will be enough.

```sql
SELECT Brand
FROM Table
GROUP BY Brand
HAVING SUM(unitsold) > 500
```

If you want to apply at year level, you can apply group at year level also.

```sql
SELECT Brand, Year(Date)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Brand, Year(Date)
HAVING SUM(unitsold) > 500
```